# Elementary Probability - Fish Problem - Find Probability of Intersection ? - Query Bayes Theorum?

Tags: probability

A fishmonger has three salmons and two sardines in his stand.

A customer will buy two fishes and does not care of the type of fish as they are both tasty fish. Assume customer purchases fish randomly.

What is probability customer with choose one salmon and one sardine?

## My Attempt:

P(A = Sardine) = 2/5 = 0.4

P(B = Salmon) = 3/5 = 0.6

P (A Intersection B) = P(B | A) * P(A) = Answer

Find therefore : P(B | A) = P(A UNION B) / P(A)

Find therefore?: P(A UNION B) = ?

I'm really confused as to how I'm supposed to solve this trival question I when I have no idea as to find P(A UNION B) to find P(B | A) to be find P(A Intersection B).

I'm sure i'm overcomplicating this and would appreciate help to resolve this.

Comment: $\frac25=0.4{}$

Comment: Thank you John - I've corrected P(A) accordingly.

Comment: Your events aren't clearly outlined. Note that the probability of drawing a Sardine on the 1st draw is different from the probability of drawing a Sardine on the 2nd draw, but with your notation it seems that both these are contained in event A. An alternative way of thinking about this problem that is: to get one salmon and sardine, either the person has to pick a salmon on the 1st and sardine on the 2nd or a sardine on the 1st and salmon on the 2nd. Just calculate these probabilities and sum them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is by looking at the two ways the fish can be chosen:

**1.**

$$P(\text{chooses Sardine then Salmon})=P(\text{Sardine}_1)P(\text{Salmon}_2|\text{Sardine}_1)=\frac25\times\frac34=\frac3{10}$$

**2.**

$$P(\text{chooses Salmon then Sardine)}=P(\text{Salmon}_1)P(\text{Sardine}_2|\text{Salmon}_1)=\frac35\times\frac24=\frac3{10}$$

Adding these together, you get the answer of $\dfrac6{10}=0.6$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since you are choosing w/o replacement, this is a *hypergeometric distribution,*

which can be solved as $Pr = \dfrac {\binom31\binom21}{\binom52} = 0.6$